# Post file array with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, http-post, multipartform-data, php-curl

I want to post an array of files to a server using PHP and curl. In HTML it looks as follows:

```
<form method="POST" type="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="fieldx" value="123"/>
    <input type="file" name="localfile[]"/>
    <input type="file" name="localfile[]"/>
</form>
```

The same should be done with CURL:

```
$postParameters['fieldx'] = "123";
$postParameters['localfile'] = array("fulllocalfilepath1", "fulllocalfilepath2");

$request = curl_init('http://server.abc');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    $postParameters
);  
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rawData = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```

But the server does not receive the `localfile` array when using CURL. What is the correct command for sending the files?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:

```
$postParameters['fieldx'] = "123";
$postParameters['localfile[0]'] = new cURLFile("fulllocalfilepath1", "mime", "readable name 1");
$postParameters['localfile[1]'] = new cURLFile("fulllocalfilepath2", "mime", "readable name 2");
$request = curl_init('http://server.abc');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt(
    $request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    $postParameters
);  
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$rawData = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```

Comment: you can also do `$postParameters['localfile']=>array((new cURLFile("fulllocalfilepath1", "mime", "readable name 1")), (new cURLFile("fulllocalfilepath2", "mime", "readable name 2")));`